# How to change vim working directory when navigating on NERDtree

Tags: events, vim, nerdtree, working-directory, autocmd

in NERDtree if you press `C` it changes the root of the NERDtree for the folder under the cursor. i'd like to change vim's working directory (like when you use: `:lcd \path\to\directory`) by using this command. anyone knows a way of doing it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the option `NERDTreeChDirMode` to value `2` this will change vim's CWD when the tree root is changed.

> 'NERDTreeChDirMode'
>
> Values: 0, 1 or 2.
>   Default: 0.
>
> Use this option to tell the script when (if at all) to change the current
>    working directory (CWD) for vim.
>
> If it is set to 0 then the CWD is never changed by the NERD tree.
>
> If set to 1 then the CWD is changed when the NERD tree is first loaded to the
>    directory it is initialized in. For example, if you start the NERD tree with
>        `:NERDTree /home/marty/foobar`
>
> then the CWD will be changed to /home/marty/foobar and will not be changed
>    again unless you init another NERD tree with a similar command.
>
> If the option is set to 2 then it behaves the same as if set to 1 except that
>    the CWD is changed whenever the tree root is changed. For example, if the CWD
>    is /home/marty/foobar and you make the node for /home/marty/foobar/baz the new
>    root then the CWD will become /home/marty/foobar/baz.